# Date format in php using regular expression

Tags: php, regex

Hai, any can help me to change the ***"Wed Sep 29 14:47:37 +0000 2010"*** to **"Sep 29,2010 at 2:47PM"** using regular expression in PHP?

Answer (score 8):

You can use `strtotime`. No need for regular expression.

```
date('M j, Y \a\t g:i A', strtotime('Wed Sep 29 14:47:37 +0000 2010'));
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the functions [date](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) and [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php):

```
$str = 'Wed Sep 29 14:47:37 +0000 2010';
$timestamp = strtotime($str);

echo date('M j, Y', $timestamp).' at '.date('g:i A', $timestamp);;
```